# ViewPager is not Working when i am trying to Navigate from one fragment to other

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using `ViewPager` for my application in which i have 5 `Fragments` ,i have two ways to navigate from one `Fragment` to other  one is by using `ViewPager` horizontal swap and the second one is i have  navigation `button` in each page by click on that i can navigate through `Fragments`,but when i am using Navigation `Button` my `ViewPager` is not  working  means i am not able to perform horizontal swap.Is Anybody has any idea how to resolve it.

Comment: Gimme some code please, and these text wont convey much

Comment: i have edited is it clear or shall i post the complete code.

Comment: If the answer posted is not right you might need to post your code

Answer (score 1):

```
((ViewPager) mView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id)).setCurrentItem(youId);
```

Use this method to change the tab inside your `ViewPager`, instead of creating `new Fragment`

Comment: thanks for the quick replay but this is not what i want..  i am posting the code.

Comment: Okay when pressing on back button you are not seeing the view pager right?

Comment: yes when i am pressing back button it's     finishes the application and one more thing when i am pressing Next Button the view pager is not working..

Comment: OnBackButton of the FrgmentActivity you are finishing the activity

Comment: so what should do i need to implement there and why i am not able  to horizontal swap .

Comment: You should be implementing pagination in fragments, because you already replacing the fragment from fragment transaction so on click on back the fragment wont be there

Comment: comment your onBackPressed() function and instead of replace try add() in fragment transaction

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` to your main activity as well as the following functions.

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int index) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "ConnectProfileActivity::onPageSelected");
    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.getTabAt(index).select();        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I Solved My Own Question  just i have to call the `FragmentActivity` in which i am adding the fragments in the `viewpager`.
Like this

```
public void OnClick(View v){
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),MyFragmentActivity.class)
startIntent(i);
```

But the problem is it will always starts the pages from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your OnClick function put the below code

ViewPager vp=(ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(ViewPagerId);

Comment: please read my question again here i am pressing a button inside a fragment .so fragment has its own layout and i cant reference ViewPager there it will throw null.

Comment: Using getActivity() method you will get an initialized ViewPager object but when you use mView.findViewById you will get a null pointer Exception

Comment: i am not using the viewpager layout in my fragment layout so its not possible to use the ids here in fragment is there any alternate way.